# LHC observables that gives you the number of Jet Constituents

Tags: large-hadron-collider

What is the name of a observable in LHC that will somehow count the number of constituents of a jet. Say the number of neutral or charged constituents of a jet.

Comment: In Delphes, they call this one NCharged (for the total number of charged constituents of a jets ) and NNeutrals (for the total number of Neutral Constituents of a jets). What is the corresponding names in LHC ?